# discord.py make bot send message when user starts streaming

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot to send a message to a specified channel, when I start livestreaming on twitch. so far I'm fiddling with getting the right "activity" from my status, which represents, that I'm streaming. This is what I got so far :

```py
class Stream(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Streamingstatus loaded")
    
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel (751954378772185149)
        if after.activity is not None and after.activity.name == '#Twitch or so?' and after.id == 254375451084980224 and guild.id == 670015807551438874:
                print(before.activity)
                print(after.activity)
                if after.activity.title.startswith(#streaming) and before.activity.title != after.activity.title:
                        await channel.send("Spleens went live on twitch right now! Watch him making a fool out of himself!")
```

Thanks in advance for any help!^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are checking `activity.name` while the correct would be to check `activity.type`. Also to check if a user is streaming you want to check if `activity.type` is `discord.ActivityType.streaming`. I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve in some lines of your code, but to check if the user is streaming just do this:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
    try:
        activity_type = after.activity.type
    except:
        pass
    # Here we check if the user is streaming
    if activitity_type is discord.ActivityType.streaming:
        # Do X if he is streaming
    else:
        # Do Y if he is not streaming
```

Comment: how can I make it that my bot only looks for the activity status of a certain user? that's what I was trying with `after.id == 254375451084980224`. I don't want my bot to send this message when anyone else might stream via twitch on my server.
Thank you for providing this piece of code!

Comment: What you are trying to do is right, it would be: `if activitity_type is discord.ActivityType.streaming and after.id == 254375451084980224:`

Comment: okay got it so far. The only error I got so far was the following: 

```python 
Ignoring exception in on_member_update Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/rachel/cogs/streamcog.py", line 20, in on_member_update     activity_type = after.activity.type AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Comment: That will happen when the user has no activity set, just check if `activity` is None.

Comment: I don't really understood, what you meant with that. Does this mean, that it is normal? Should I ignore it? Sorry, if I missunderstood.. :(